# Special chars changing on compilation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve it, I have some special chars for operations in my code, I have these lines:

```
            If CType(gridProductos.Rows(i).Cells(dtCabecerasGrilla(0)("Descuento ésta venta")).FindControl("txtDescuentoPrecioVenta"), TextBox).Text <> "" Then
            fila.Item("DescuentoPrecioVenta") = CDbl(CType(gridProductos.Rows(i).Cells(dtCabecerasGrilla(0)("Descuento ésta venta")).FindControl("txtDescuentoPrecioVenta"), TextBox).Text.Replace("%", ""))
        Else
            fila.Item("DescuentoPrecioVenta") = CDbl(gridProductos.Rows(i).Cells(dtCabecerasGrilla(0)("DescuentoPrecioVenta")).Text)
        End If
```

but, when I compile shows me this error:

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MguCP.png)

It seems like the the compiler is using Ã© instead of é, I have other pages with the same operation but I don't have this problem there.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I would guess you need to make sure that you have saved your code in unicode/utf8.

Comment: I have already did that [Saving with unicode/utf8](https://imgur.com/a/YSckDPX) and it's giving me the same error

Comment: It's saved without BOM. It is possible that the file has been modified with another text editor. Missing the BOM, the file has been saved with the wrong encoding (a local encoding, possibly). Save it as UTF8 with its BOM, re-write the affected letters and re-save it (take a close look at the path VS proposes when saving with encoding).

Comment: NICE! that solved my problem, All i had to do is [SaveEncoding UTF8 with BOM](https://imgur.com/a/YSckDPX). ty @Jimi